# Removing copied values from 1 record to the next in a table

Tags: sql-server, self-join

I have a single table such as this:

```
 Date,    Reader, EQP ID, Reading
8/1/2015,  Jim,     1,      100
8/2/2015,  Jim,     1,      100
8/3/2015,  Jim,     1,      110
8/4/2015,  Jim,     1,      110
8/1/2015,  Jim,     2,      355
8/2/2015,  Jim,     2,      362
8/3/2015,  Jim,     2,      362
8/4/2015,  Jim,     2,      365
```

The value of Reading increases over time as in a meter read.

The issue is that sometimes a reading used the previous day is reused instead of a new reading being performed and logged.

I want to update the duplicate read values and set them to 0 if they're the same as the previous day; this would indicate days where meters weren't read.

The end result I'm looking for is the following:

```
  Date,   Reader,   EQP ID,  Value
8/1/2015,   Jim,       1,     100
8/2/2015,   Jim,       1,       0
8/3/2015,   Jim,       1,     110
8/4/2015,   Jim,       1,       0
8/1/2015,   Jim,       2,     355
8/2/2015,   Jim,       2,     362
8/3/2015,   Jim,       2,       0
8/4/2015,   Jim,       2,     365
```

I'm thinking that I should be using a self-join with a Top 1 clause, but can't quite get the syntax down.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why you aren't able to use the self-join? Are you joining on all the key fields? Can you please show your SQL. Also if you are using 2012 you can use Lag function.

Comment: Which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: What if reading is same for 8/1 and 8/2? How do you make sure its a previous day's reading and the reading is not 100 again for 8/2,Jim,1?

Comment: what is the key/unique value date?

Comment: DB is 2008 R2, but I have SSMS for 2008R2, 2012, and 2014. So... I could use any version of SSMS to query, couldn't I?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query. This will work in all versions of sql server 2008+:

```
select 
    t1.Date,
    t1.Reader,
    t1.[EQP ID],
    case 
        when t2.reading is null or t2.reading<>t1.reading 
        then t1.reading 
        else 0 
    end as reading  
from
    (
      select 
          row_number() over(partition by reader,[eqp id]  order by date asc) as r,
          * 
      from tbl
    ) t1
left join 
    (
      select 
          row_number() over(partition by reader,[eqp id]  order by date asc) as r,
          * 
      from tbl
    ) t2
on t1.Reader=t2.reader 
and t1.[eqp id]=t2.[eqp id] 
and t1.r=t2.r+1
```

demo sql fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0a60/2

in case you were looking for update query

```
update tm
  set reading=t.reading
from tbl tm
  inner join 
(
 select 
    t1.Date,
    t1.Reader,
    t1.[EQP ID],
    case 
        when t2.reading is null or t2.reading<>t1.reading 
        then t1.reading 
        else 0 
    end as reading  
  from
  (
      select 
         row_number() over(partition by reader,[Eqp id] order by date asc) as r,
         * 
      from tbl
   ) t1
  left join 
  (
      select 
         row_number() over(partition by reader,[Eqp id] order by date asc) as r,
         * 
      from tbl
   ) t2
   on t1.Reader=t2.reader 
   and t1.[eqp id]=t2.[eqp id] and 
   t1.r=t2.r+1 
)t
on tm.[Date]=t.[date] and tm.reader=t.reader and tm.[eqp id]=t.[eqp id] and t.reading=0

select * from tbl
```

demo fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0a60/8

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server 2012 or later version it is pretty simple....

```
SELECT * 
     ,CASE WHEN 
       LAG(Reading) OVER (PARTITION BY 
                          Reader,EQPID,Reading 
                          ORDER BY [Date]) =  Reading 
      THEN 0 ELSE Reading END [New_Reading]
FROM TableName
ORDER BY   EQPID,[Date]
```

### [`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/4518)

### Update

```
WITH X AS 
 (
      SELECT * 
         ,CASE WHEN 
           LAG(Reading) OVER (PARTITION BY 
                              Reader,EQPID,Reading 
                              ORDER BY [Date]) =  Reading 
          THEN 0 ELSE Reading END [New_Reading]
    FROM TableName
  )
UPDATE X 
  SET Reading  = New_Reading
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update t
set t.Reading = 0
from tbl t
inner join tbl t0 on 
  t0.date = dateadd(d, -1, t.date) and
  t0.reader = t.reader and
  t0.[eqp id] = t.[eqp id] and
  t0.reading = t.reading

select * from tbl
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50b35/1 (thanks @DhruvJoshi for template)

The same without SQL UPDATE:

```
select 
  t.date, 
  t.reader, 
  t.[eqp id], 
  case 
    when t0.date is null
    then t.reading
    else 0
  end as reading
from tbl t
left join tbl t0 on 
  t0.date = dateadd(d, -1, t.date) and
  t0.reader = t.reader and
  t0.[eqp id] = t.[eqp id] and
  t0.reading = t.reading
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50b35/3

Your self join assumption is correct - join on all columns expect Date, for Date join on yesterday